# Why the European Union choose to use a Nazi flag?

Tags: europe, nazism

I wonder why the EU uses a Nazi flag like the one from this picture?

> [image]
>   <sub>Source: https://qph.fs.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-32598a7f739cbfe57c03e4011891984b</sub>

Comment: Guessing here that you read "a theory" about that? Perhaps around the picture where you stumbled across this? Someone claiming it "to be so". Or is this your own observation? You may want to document this 'research' here.

Answer (score 16):

They didn't.

1. That isn't a Nazi flag.
2. The EU didn't use that flag.

---

That picture seems to be from the [1939 American Nazi organisation rally](https://rarehistoricalphotos.com/american-nazi-organization-rally-madison-square-garden-1939/) at Madison Square Garden.  The flags in the background are variations on the familiar '*[Stars and Stripes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_of_the_United_States)*':

[image: Stars & Stripes]

and the *[Betsy Ross flag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Betsy_Ross_flag)*:

[image: Betsy Ross Flag]

---

The picture is just another example of far-right extremists wrapping themselves in the flag of the country they purport to represent.  In this case, history shows that they were not representative of the majority view in the United States at all.

As the article cited above observes:

> In February 1939 Kuhn and the Bund held their largest rally in Madison Square Garden — ironically, one which marked the beginning of the end for the organization.

The German-born American leader of the German American Bund, Fritz Julius Kuhn, was deported from the United States back to Germany after the war.

It's perhaps worth noting that there is a flag bearing the symbol of the Bund between the two American flags in the picture linked in the question.  The lack of resemblance between that flag and the EU flag is striking!

---

There doesn't appear to be any suggestion that the design of the [EU flag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_of_Europe) was based on the design of the Betsy Ross flag.  The circle as a symbol of unity is a common theme (see, for example, [Squaring the Circle - Geometry in Art & Architecture](https://www.math.dartmouth.edu/~matc/math5.geometry/unit9/unit9.html), by Paul Calter).

As the Council of Europe described the design in 1955:

> 'Against the blue sky of the Western world, the stars represent the peoples of Europe in a circle, a symbol of unity. Their number shall be invariably set at twelve, the symbol of completeness and perfection'.

— [Council of Europe](https://web.archive.org/web/20090528195931/http://www.coe.int/t/dgal/dit/ilcd/Fonds/Themes/Flags/Res%2855%2932_en.pdf). Paris, 7–9 December 1955

[image: EU Flag]

Comment: That picture linked to in Q has so few stripes, what's up with that 'variation'? & compare the Q-flag strs number with EU? –– Btw. *the* Nazis were at least original enough to bring in their own flag, openly despising the (real/former) flag of the country they represented.

Comment: Just a guess, there is a similarity of EU flag with CS-Star&Bars as well. This then with only 3 stripes.

Comment: @LangLangC The cantons of both the _Stars & Stripes_, and the _Betsy Ross flag_ have 7 stripes have seven stripes beside them. In effect, they've cut away the stripes below the cantons. The Betsy Ross flag has 13 stars representing the 13 states. (The CS Stars & Bars also has 13 stars - for the same reason - but only 3 stripes).

Comment: @LangLangC The circle as a symbol of unity is a common theme. From the 1955 Council of Europe description: '_Against the blue sky of the Western world, the stars represent the peoples of Europe in a circle, a symbol of unity_'.   Of course, opponents of the EU have chosen to interpret the symbolism differently, occasionally quoting Tolkien's [Ring Verse](http://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Ring_Verse): '_One Ring to rule them all, One Ring to find them, One Ring to bring them all, and in the darkness bind them_'. I guess it's a question of perception.

Comment: Yes? But "why did the American Nazis cut away half the stripes" was my question. Never seen that and haven't looked into it. Are they still variations or something different? (And btw, in that picture in Q:  there *is* a Nazi flag, in the centre, although barely with any resemblance to, well, official EU symbolism, or even one of the strange proposals that were around for a time)

Comment: @LangLangC I believe it's called a 'pull-down flag', or 'pulldown flag', and they [aren't that uncommon](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=american+flag+pulldown&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjdnImdp7PeAhWlNOwKHaz1BK8Q_AUIDigB&biw=1344&bih=695) even today.  Not something particular to the Bund in 1939.

Comment: Perhaps a non-US person wouldn't realize this, but the banner on the far right is **clearly** a representation of George Washington. I mean, there is 0 doubt of this.

Comment: @T.E.D. That is mentioned in the article I cited. It also says why the Bund preferred a representation of Washington as a symbol, rather than - say - Thomas Jefferson or James Madison Jr.

Comment: Hah. I'm not even sure that needs an explanation. Washington is the unimpeachable symbol of the country. That headshot of him used to be in every single classroom. I don't think those aholes could have been trying harder to make themselves look American without ending up with bald eagle poo all over the stage.

Comment: @T.E.D. Sorry. Perhaps I should have said an explanation for those unfamiliar with US History (a group that - sadly - includes some Americans, but - happily - not all non-Americans).  ;-)

Comment: The number of stripes is consistent with the number of stripes to the right of the star field on the official flag. It's probably done to keep the same proportions. Another example is the old hanging banners of Nuremberg. The city shield has six stripes in it but the banner only had five to that the outer edges would both be red and create a symmetrical design. The modern banner is quite different, just red and white halves with the shield in the middle.